# Reading multiple Excel files and merge them sheet-wise

Tags: r, excel, vba

I have close to 50 Excel files. Which have the following sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 and Sheet4). And the columns in each sheets are identical across all the 50 files.
I need to read each excel file and merge the 4 sheets data in 4 dataframes/4 excel files.

I tried to include `for` loop to read the 50 files and store the workbook as a temp variable. But to read each sheet from them and binding it to a final variable is where I'm stuck.

Okay with a VBA solution as well!

Comment: This is easy accomplished by Power Query. Did you tried it?

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover, this does not specify merging the respective sheets. or am i missing something?

Comment: @ALeXceL, nope i do not have much knowledge about Power Query. can you share some resources?

Comment: There's a lot about Power Query on the web. Here on SO you find a lot too. I'm reading an e-book found on Amazon.com(.br) that costs about $5. I can't post details about it here. With PQ I compiled a bank account statement that accounts for the last 30 months. One sheet/month (HTM - fake XLS) . For the next month, my client will save the corresponding sheet in the specified folder and that's it. Opening the main workbook all 31 months will be there, compiled. A PivotTable is the natural complement in this case.

Comment: But you didn't post your question as required by Stack Overflow. You should post your initial effort, as well as a sample, even with dummy data, so that another participant can assist you, even with substantially different code.

Answer (score 0):

This will process each excel and merge the sheets for each excel to one df. The function will return a list of dataframes. The dataframes are binded together after the list is returned from the function.

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

files <- list.files(path="C:/data/55423/originals/r_test/",
                        pattern="*.xlsx",
                        full.names=TRUE)

allsheets <- function(filename) {
    sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
    x <- lapply(sheets, function(x) 
        transform(readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet=x), sheetname=x))
    return(x)
}

df <- lapply(files, allsheets)%>% bind_rows()
```